# Weird Javascript:void(0) code in my website

Tags: php, javascript

Hello i am bit newbiew of coding but very well expirienced with WP.
I am having this website ([www.kefaloniataxiservice.gr](http://www.kefaloniataxiservice.gr))
there is this kind in my website (INSPECT CODE) that according to Lightspeed is conflicting the SEO of my page.
i tried to find with VS Code this code but couldnt find it, even trying only **w-header-show** got me to some CSS and JS code that if i deleted it nothing changed.
Also i tried to download my DB from PhpMyAdmin and search the entire DB with VS Code aswell but couldnt find anything,
any luck?
Notice: Μένου means Menu.

````
        <a class="w-header-show" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Μενού</span></a>
    <div class="w-header-overlay"></div>
    <script>```
````

Comment: It's an old way of making links where you expect to add a click handler event in script, but if there isn't one then do nothing. I can't see why it would have any impact on your page SEO.

Comment: thats what Lightspeed says, open Google chrome and lightspeed my website and you will understand